# Regular expression to validate the text with these characters

Tags: regex, validation

I am looking for a regular expression which accepts the text with spaces and consists of the below characters. Can one of you quickly guide me through? I have been trying to create one, but it is taking too much time to do.

```
A-Z,a-z,0-9, , , :,;(,),-,_#,/,\,.,&,`
```

I should be able to control the whole length as well. The input can include multiple words.

Comment: *i have been trying to develop, but taking time todo this.* We will be happy to help you if you try and fail, but you have to try first...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What does your source text looks like? RegEx has to be customized to suit your needs.

Comment: If you provide the language you're working with and some context source code we'd be able to help you more.

Comment: you dont show what you have tried and you have very low acceptance too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP should show a minimal understanding of the problem by showing the attempt to resolve the problem, the desired output and the problems encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
/^[\w\s:;.,&`()\/\\-]+$/
```

Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\w\s:;.,&`()\/\\-]+     any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " "), ':', ';', '.', ',', '&', '`',
                           '(', ')', '/', '\', '-' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: thanks macek. this works for me.
jaypal - I would like to use this exp to validate address fields and some comments,etc.